# Image Uploading with thumbnails original ratio in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, image-uploading, image-resizing, image-compression

I want to upload jpg file with asp fileupload.

When I choose a jpg file first it will upload it doing nothing as same as in my computer.

Second one it will reduce image for thumbnail which width is 250px and auto height with original ratio.

And thumbnail image compressed 60% quality with jpg compression, it won't upload max file size.

Second one will be renamed *(original is abc01)* `abc01_250`.

Just I choose one file and click save. It will save two files. How can I do that?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear about what exactly you would like to do. Maybe you should consider expanding on it. Are you looking to save 2 separate files - the original and thumbnail? Is 60% optimised meaning the original file dimensions should be reduced by 60%?

Comment: I edited, is it a bit more clear?